# In Bash: Can I treat the list of args in a for loop as a list?

Tags: bash, for-loop, arguments

Can I treat the list of args in a for loop as a list? Can I access the elements in the list with a list index ?
MAke this pseudo code run:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2; do
    j=the next element in the for loop
    echo current is $i and next is $j
done
```

output should be for the first iteration:

> current is 1 and next is 2

What will it be for the second iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
declare -a data=(1 2)

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#data[@]} ; i++ )) do
    elem=${data[$i]}
    j=$((i+1))
    nextElem=${data[$j]}
    echo current is $i $elem and next is $j $nextElem
done
```

Related:

- [Bash Shell Script Iterate Through Array Values](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/636/bash-shell-script-iterate-through-array-values/)
- [The Ultimate Bash Array Tutorial with 15 Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

I feel bash people always go for the most complicated thing. Could you also live with:

```
# Let's say we want to access elements 1,3,3,7 in this order
cur=$1
for next in "$3" "$3" "$7"
do
    printf "cur: %s, next: %s\n" "$cur" "$next"
    cur=$next
done
```

`What will it be for the`<strike>`second`</strike>`last iteration of the loop?`

If you can't answer that, me neither. That usually means you think too complicated. My above version which I consider simpler does not have this corner in a quite natural way, because it differs in a way such that the last iteration is "missing".

Answer (score 1):

There is no (practical) way to spy on what the next elements in a `for` loop will be. You have to store the values elsewhere and/or use a different type of loop.

You can use either the positional parameters, or arrays.

The positional parameters are guaranteed not to be sparse.

```
set -- {a..f}
n=1

while ((n<=$#)); do
    printf 'cur: %s%.s%s\n' "${!n}" $((++n)) ${!n:+", next: ${!n}"}
done
```

Bash arrays are sparse. If you're not iterating over values directly using a `for` loop, you should use indices instead.

```
arr=({a..f}) idx=("${!arr[@]}")

while ((n<${#idx[@]})); do
    printf 'cur: %s%s\n' "${arr[idx[n]]}" ${idx[++n]:+", next: ${arr[idx[n]]}"}
done
```

Even if you think you can guarantee contiguous elements, this approach isn't a bad idea.

Output for both examples:

```
cur: a, next: b
cur: b, next: c
cur: c, next: d
cur: d, next: e
cur: e, next: f
cur: f
```